# Hessian identity in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python

The Hessian matrix obtained in my minimize optimization with bounds is a identity matrix in a multivariate vacisec model with 6 parameters throught a kalman filter  and a Maximum Likelihood (Normal) that I programmed

```
minimize(myloglikvalue,
         parameters,
         bounds=((None,None),(1.0,None),(1e-10,1.0),(0.0,None),(-1.0,1.0),(1e-10,1.0)))
```

Do you know whats the problem here?

Comment: Hi can you provide more code of your program? and what specifically is the problem (what is unexpected) you have?

Comment: My code it’s simply a Kalman Filter where the error covariance matrix and mean vector are use in the multidimensional log likelihood function and make a sume for every observation. Myloglikevalue its a function that gives this sume when you give certain parameters (Vasicek model). The issue it’s that when I minimize -Myloglikevalue given a set of initial parameters, the hess_inv of the function scipy.optimize returns me a Identity matrix instead the inverse of the Hessian matrix.